# How can I find the maximum difference of two elements in an array, given some constraints?

Tags: c++, arrays

Problem:

Find the maximum difference of two elements in an array such that the index of the element of the larger element is greater than the index of the smaller element.

Note: I will use zero-based indexing.

Example:

`array = {1,2,3,4,5}`

The maximum difference will be 4. The index of '5' is greater than the index of '1', and it has the maximum difference in sum (5 - 1 = 4).

Example 2:

`array  = {5,3,2,4,6}`

The maximum difference of this array will be 4. The index of '6' is greater than the index of '2', and it has the maximum difference in sum (6 - 2 = 4).

I have tried implementing a brute force solution, but it runs in O(n^2).

```
int main(){
  int n = 5;
  int arr[n] num_array = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int maximum_value = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
      if (num_array[j] - num_array[i]>maximum_value) 
      {
        maximum_value = num_array[j] - num_array[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This solution gives Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) and I could not find a way to optimise it.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-difference-between-two-elements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by taking the difference of elements with the minimum element found so far. Here's how you can do this:

```
int arr[5]={101,2,100,5,1},min=arr[0],i,diff=-99999;  //You can initialize diff to be arr[1]-arr[0] for simplicity.
    for(i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]-min>diff)   //If the difference is greater than the maximum difference, then update maximum difference
        diff=arr[i]-min;
        if(arr[i]<min)   //If the array element is smaller than the previous minimum element, then update minimum
        min=arr[i];
    }
```

**NOTE:** I initialized `diff` to -99999 upon **assuming** that any difference is not less than -99999. For simplicity, and to be on the safe side, you can initialize `diff=arr[1]-arr[0]`.